# Angular 7 - Error getting while creating Angular App

Tags: angular, angular7

I am Getting below errors

CREATE HealthCareApp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (251 bytes)
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"3.3.0-beta.1","peer'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-14T18_53_52_801Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.

Angular version
Node version - v10.15.1
NPM version  - 6.4.1
Angular - Angular CLI: 7.3.1

Answer (score 2):

1. `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm cache clean --force`, and then `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your node version to 11 or the latest.

you need to run the following.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Still Facing same issue :(

Comment: run ng version in the project dir

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '\node_modules'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '\node_modules'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:806:3)
    at VersionCommand.run (C:\Users\manik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\version-impl.js:48:41)
    at VersionCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\manik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:124:31)
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)